# i can't login to my magento backend

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I installed magento 2.1.1 on a WAMP Server and the installation was successful. I was able to login to backend of the Magento but everything changed when i installed a theme. According to the documentation of the theme I have to create a new database in `phpmyadmin` and import a `database.sql` which came with the theme.

After this I have to edit `app/etc/env.php` and change the following: `dbname`, `username` and `password` with the one I use when creating the database. I followed the procedure and everything worked well but since then I couldn't login to the back-end of the Magento. I have search on the internet for two days now but all posts which I found couldn't resolve my issue so far.

Please  help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed your database to another, then the user you originally created won't exist anymore for the Magento install to let you in.

In this case, you're best off creating a new admin user.

You can do this using the Magento commmand line tool:

```html
<path_to_magento>/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Password1234" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Depending on your setup, you might need to run:

```html
<path_to_php>php <path_to_magento>/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Password1234" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Comment: Thanks for your contributions and answers. i have resolved it by requesting from the company that sold the theme to me, the username and password they use in admin_user of the database and they send it to me.